# Structural isomers given a molar mass

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers

> How many structural isomers are possible for compound containing $\ce{C}$, $\ce{H}$ and $\ce{O}$ atoms only with their molar masses $100$ as well as the isomers are simultaneously ketones
>
> 1. 3
> 2. 4
> 3. 5
> 4. 6

Answer is (4).

The problem I had was I couldn't understand the question properly. I don't understand what do they mean by simultaneous ketones. But I tried this in the photo below:

[image]

Comment: Ok It's a question from my study material for isomers. Whatever they asked in that question is given above. I know the answer which I will update

Comment: They want you to find all the structural isomers all (1) containing C,H and O (2) of molar mass 100 (3) and are ketones. They should satisfy all these three conditions _simultaneously_. Getting it?

Comment: Well the problem seem to have forgotten that isotopes of carbon, hydrogen and oxygen exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limiting the answer to compounds which only have oxygen as a ketone, and ignoring isotopes of carbon, hydrogen and oxygen, there are two chemical formulas which have a mass of 100.

Isomers of $\ce{C6H12O}$ (Molecular Mass = 100) that are ketones:
 
1) Hexan-2-one.
2) Hexan-3-one.
3) 4-Methylpentan-2-one.
4) 3-Methylpentan-2-one.
5) 3,3-dimethylbutan-2-one.

Source: [Wikepedia - $\ce{C6H12O}$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C6H12O)

Isomers of $\ce{C5H8O2}$ (Molecular Mass = 100) that are ketones:
 
1)pentan-2,3-dione.
2)pentan-2,4-dione.

Hence in total we have **seven** possibilities.

Comment: For $\ce{C5H8O2}$ there are both both pentan-2,3-dione and pentan-2,4-dione. 2-Methyldihydrofuran-3(2H)-one is both an ether and a ketone.

Comment: Oh yes! So the options must be incorrect. Question doesn’t place any condition on no. of oxygen atoms. Should I add them too?

Comment: Surely pentan-2,4-dione should be added.